# How do I prevent SwiftUI's TabView from moving vertically when dragging?

Tags: swiftui

How do I prevent SwiftUI's Tabview with PageTabViewStyle from moving vertically when dragging? The horizontal movement helps indicate that you can swipe to change pages but since you can't change pages vertically the up and down movement is misleading and pointless.